# Select Text Using DoubleClick from WebDriver Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to do double click on search inputbox of google page and it should be selected

This is my code :

```
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.navigate().to("http://www.google.com");
    WebElement oWE = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.name("q")));
    if (oWE.isDisplayed()) {
       System.out.println("Displayed");
       oWE.sendKeys("abcd");
       driver.findElement(By.id("gbqfb")).click();
       Actions oAction = new Actions(driver);
       oAction.moveToElement(oWE);
       oAction.doubleClick(oWE).build().perform();
    }
```

but text is not selected.

1.Why it is not working?

2.We always use By.ID,By.name etc why we do not use ById.Id ByName.name etc
if we can use this where it should be used if not why we did not use this?

Comment: @user1177636 for my question 1.Actually here I just gave an example like google but in really I ask this question because I just select the text and go for the context menu and there some option for check the spell check. 2.for my second question I ask this question because if we for ById class then we find that it is like public static class ById extends By implements Serializable so what is the significance of  Serializable?

Comment: do you want to select all the text by double clicking the inputbox?

Comment: @user2720250 yeap I want to select this by double click on google search input box

Comment: i put a answer check that...

Comment: i also tried to select the text from double clicking but it didn't work.But double works fine at other instances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to select all the text you can do it like this...

driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath")).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "a"));

Comment: yeap It is good I also bypass this issue using this but can help me why double click is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is perfect: instead of trying to "double click" the web element you've given, try some other element.

Try this:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.navigate().to("http://jsbin.com/obeyu4/3");
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
    Actions act = new Actions(driver);
    act.doubleClick(driver.findElement(By.id("golink"))).perform();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
```

Comment: it is fine but I need this for textbox